# Printing a list

Tags: java, collections

```
       private String getQuery() {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                sb.append(" SELECT DISTINCT col1,   ");
                sb.append("   col2, ");
                sb.append("   col3, ");
                sb.append("   col4, ");
                sb.append("   col5, ");.....so on 
                return sb.toString();


    public List<Object[]> getDetails(Connection connection, String RequestId) throws Exception {
            List<Object[]> test = null;
            final Map<Integer, Object> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
            testMap.put(1, RequestId);
            test = executeQuery(connection, getQuery(), testMap, 100);
            return test; 
}
```

I want to print the list .I am providing

```
System.out.println(test.toString());
```

and then the `toString()` overriding method ,but it is still printing addresses .

I am trying to print like below -

```
    System.out.println(test.toString());

@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "className [getQuery()=" + getQuery() + "]";
    }
```

Comment: how are you printing the list

Comment: @ankur-singhal-: please look at the Edit ..toString() method generated using eclipse source -> generate toString() option

Comment: So you are actually trying to print `query`

Comment: No .Actually I want to print the values .Can u tell me what do I add in the toString() method ??

Comment: value of what, your `toString()` method prints query only, post the code once your method `getDetails()` returns `List<Object[]>`, do you actually wants to print the output

Comment: I am puting my S.O.P after it has returned test only but still printing addresses.

Comment: if have tried to match your question, posted a sample answer, please go through this, `toString()` prints `toString()` of List class, you have to iterate elements and then print

Comment: @ankur-singhal: thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample program for printing object values

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        Object[] object1 = { 2, 3 };
        Object[] object2 = { 5, 8 };
        list.add(object1);
        list.add(object2);
        System.out.println(list.toString()); // prints address here

        for (Object[] myArray : list) {
            for (Object obj : myArray) {
                System.out.println(obj); // print elements
            }
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@659e0bfd, [Ljava.lang.Object;@2a139a55]
2
3
5
8
```